# How to add a databound table to a collectionview grid in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I know that Xamarin XAML does not support an HTML table:

```
<table><th/><tr><td>Data Here</td></tr></table>
```

I have a databound collection view that gets data from a SQLite database, let's say it's the Person class:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>                        
<Grid Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TABLEDATA}" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

When I populate the database there is data that is dynamic and will not always fill one row. Sometimes it's one row, sometimes it's eight rows, like a person's work history.

I save the data as a string with an `Envirnment.Newline();` deliminator to make the text readable and fill the database field "`TABLEDATA`".

I want to fill that database field with text like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and databind it to something in Xamarin XAML that will render it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code, create an observable collection of your object type:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourModel> objList;
public ObservableCollection<YourModel> ObjList
{
    get { return objList; }
    set
    {
        objList = value;
    }
}
```

Populate your data to the list:

```
ObjList = new ObservableCollection<....>(){ ....};
```

In XAML create a grid inside a CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                   
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       />
                <Label 
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Att1}"
                      />
                     
                      <Label 
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="{Binding Att2}"
                        />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

Alternatively, [check](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started) the DataGrid in Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank You, This is pretty much what I currently have.  Where you have your labels in your XAML - I need that to be dynamic.  Sometimes it's one label, sometimes it's 8.  Ill probably have to do it in the code behind with a loop....  Loops just seem so hacky.  Maybe when I get home I will put together an image that better shows what I am trying to accomplish.  It would be cool to have a string that is filled with defined html like code (like an html table) that the view could display as a table.

Comment: sure please elaborate what you need

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing so far:

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Color="#333130" Margin="0"></BoxView>

<!--  WE ARE LOOKING AT THE WEVIEW IN A DATABOUND COLLECTIONVIEW  Yikes!-->

                            <WebView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="#333130" 
                                     MinimumHeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                     HeightRequest="{Binding WebViewHeight}" >
                                <WebView.Source>
                                    <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding AllHTMLText}"/>
                                </WebView.Source>
                            </WebView>



                    </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Inside a CollectionView is a Grid, then there are labels that are databound that provide useful data. Some of that data is dynamic and does not display well in "Label"  I need a table to display it properly.

In the CollectionView is now a million webviews, this is terrible, but it works.
The webview gets its HTML, which is just an HTML table of data, from that database field `AllHTMLText`.  Then, when the collection view renders each table is a different size and therefore the webview does not know that.

I had to create another database field called `WebViewHeight` that gets populated with a calculated height for the webview based on how big the table is.

It's a hack, but it works.  If anyone has a better idea to improve this please post your ideas.